# Adding line to array of structures, types char* and char not matching

Tags: c, arrays, structure

im learning structures and trying to apply what ive been learning.This is my code

```
/*Name:
  Purpose:
  Notes:
  Psuedocode: OPEN FILE;TOKENIZE LINE;PLACE TOKENS INTO STRUCTURES;CONTINUE TO NEXT LINE;IF NAME MATCHES EXISTING STRUCTURE NAME TOKEN,ADD THE CREDIT AMOUNT,AND UPDATE TOTAL HOURS FOR THAT STRUCTURE
              */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void create_structures(FILE* file);/*pass file in, tokenize to get name and course,send name,course,and adress of the structure to search function*/
/*void search_add()recieve name,course token,search the strcture for match in name,if match add the credit to name,if not add name and credit to structure*/

struct info{
    char name[20];
    char course[4];
};

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("input-hw04b.txt","r");
    FILE* nf = fopen("out2.txt","w+");
    create_structures(fp);

}

void create_structures(FILE* file)
{
    struct info struct_array[30];
    char buffer[100];
    char* del = " ";
    char* token;
    int number,i,h,size;
    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file) != NULL)
    {
        i = 0;
        h = 0;
        token = strtok(buffer,del);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(i == 0 || i == 5)
            {
                printf("%s ",token);
                struct_array[h].name = token; /*PROBLEM */
                struct_array[h].course = token;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL,del);
            i = i + 1;
            h = h + 1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is at the very bottom of the code, when i tokenize each line i get tokens `Edward` and `1105`,which are type char* because of strtok, i then proceed to try to store that in `struct[h].name` and struct[h].course as an added entry into the array of structures with index h. I get this error

```
hw4b.c: In function ‘create_structures’:
hw4b.c:43:38: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
                 struct_array[h].name = token; /*PROBLEM */
                                      ^
hw4b.c:44:40: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[4]’ from type ‘char *’
                 struct_array[h].course = token;
```

ive tried to get the types to match by dereferencing, token. didnt work. thought maybe to strcopy token of type char* to a variable of type char. didnt work. Not sure what to do now in order to add Edward and 1105 into the array of structures?

Comment: You were on the right track with strcpy. Keep trying along that approach.

Answer (score 2):

`info.name` and `info.course` are character array type, so you can't assign anything to them and change their value.

You will have to use copy characters into the array.

```
strncpy(struct_array[h].name, token, 
        sizeof(struct_array[h].name)/sizeof(struct_array[h].name[0]);
#make sure there is \0 at the end
struct_array[h].name[sizeof(struct_array[h].name)/sizeof(struct_array[h].name[0]) -1] = '\0';
```

Do similar for `info.course`.

Comment: for the strcpy you simply called it, you dont assign a variable to it? like what would i assign strcpy too?

Comment: @user3686360, no. that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should deepcopy using strcpy_n or something similar function. `name` is char[20], which is allocated in stack. You cannot assign a char pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom Line: `struct_array[h].name = token;` here you are trying to assign a pointer's address to a fixed size character that is being pointed by `struct_array[h].name[0]`. we cannot assign a pointer to the character value.

Your error can be eliminated by writing `*token` (that is identical to `*(token +0)` or `token[0]`) instead of `token` in the above line. But it won't solve your problem as it will copy only one character. that is `token[0]` will be copied to `struct_array[h].name[0]`.

When you write `struct info struct_array[30];`, at the runtime fixed size memory is allocated for your array. Memory size will be `30*(sizeof(struct info))`. And `struct_array` will be holding the beginning address of allocated memory chunk.

The lines `struct_array[h].name = token;`, is invalid. Because `name` field of your `struct info` structure is not a `char *`(pointer to the character). 
Assignment operator (`=`) will simply copy the value of pointer `token`. That is address address of first character of string return by strtok.

You need to copy data from buffer being pointed out by `token` to your desired variables.
you can use functions like `strcpy_n` or `strncpy`.